# Affinity Column of membrane bound receptors

Tags: enzymes, chromatography

I understand affinity columns can be used to study the ligand/enzyme affinity. But is an affinity column able to be used for membrane bound receptors? I

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic reference where Stanley Cohen and Graham Carpenter used an affinity column made out of the epidermal growth factor (EGF), and used it to purify the EGF receptor: [JBC 1980](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6246084)

Answer (score 0):

[Purifying Challenging Proteins](https://www.mcdb.ucla.edu/Research/Jacobsen/LabWebSite/PDFOthers/GESeminar.pdf)

So this is definitely something you can do, but first you need to express proteins that have a tag the affinity column is going to recognize. You can engineer a 6x his tag pretty standardly, but the procedure I'm looking at says a long 8-10 his tag might be better for insoluble proteins. You also want to be careful to place the tag at the C-terminus to avoid messing with the membrane anchoring signal at the N-terminus.

You can express these in bacteria, for example, and you'll disrupt the membrane and solubilize the proteins of interest using detergents. You have to be careful here because while some of the solubilized proteins can retain their native conformation in solution, harsh treatment with detergent can remove critical lipids affecting stability.

The purification step for his tags involves an affinity column of immobilized nickel, which binds to imidazole on histidine. After pushing the associated binding, wash and elution buffers through the column containing the sample, you should in theory have your purified protein product. You elute by washing imidazole through the column, which should competitively displace the his tag and wash the protein of interest out.

Should you lack tagged protein to begin with, you'll need to use a number of purification steps like gel filtration, ion-exchange, etc., and a little knowledge about your target protein to get a good purification though, like it's ligand for affinity binding. Give that presentation a read through!